# How to get row count of VIEW table along with Metadata information in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to get row count of VIEW table in `Snowflake` along with metadata information such as TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,CREATED,LAST_ALTERED columns from INFORMATION_SCHEMA for the specific VIEW table.Let say my VIEW table name is "V_TEST"
I can write `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB.SCHEMA.V_TEST` and get a row count for VIEW table but not sure how to merge in the table with metadata table ?

I can get TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,CREATED,LAST_CREATED using below code

```
    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,CREATED,LAST_CREATED FROM DB.Information_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='V_TEST'
```

Thanks in advance for your help and efforts!

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to get rowcount metadata of a view because a view does not have rows. A view doesn't store data unless it is materialized, so I don't think it is possible.

Comment: If its just for one table, you can put count(*) query as inline query with rest of your query. select (select count(*)...) col_alias, other_col from information_schema...;

Comment: @Pankaj..Unfortunately it's for multiple tables